# Initializing a subclass on condition from the parent class initialisation

Tags: python, matrix, subclass

I'm working with matrices for a project I'm writing in Python. I know that a lot of libraries already exist for manipulating matrices but I'm writing my own so I know exactly what's going on under the hood.

So I have a `Matrix` base class and a `Vector` subclass. Both work as expected individually but I'd like a `Matrix` to be a `Vector` if initialized with a single line or column.

I tried something like `self = Vector(...)` when the `Matrix` is initialized with the right size. But that doesn't seem to affect the object. I also thought of calling the `__init__()` method of the `Vector` class but that doesn't suffice because what I want most importantly are the `Vector`'s methods.

Is there a pythonic way of dealing with a situation like this?

Comment: Use a factory that decides on the class based on your criteria, rather than trying to do some magic with `__init__`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done, although it might not be the best way to do it. After all if the `Matrix` class is instantiated, one expect the result to be a `Matrix` instance.

One way of achieving that is to customize the constructor of the `Matrix` class:

```
class Matrix:
    def __new__(cls, nrows, ncols):
        if nrows == 1:
            inst = super(Matrix, cls).__new__(Vector)
        else:
            inst = super(Matrix, cls).__new__(cls)
        inst.nrows = nrows
        inst.ncols = ncols
        return inst

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}(nrows={}, ncols={})'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self.nrows, self.ncols)
```

Demo:

```
>>> m1 = Matrix(2, 5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Matrix(nrows=2, ncols=5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
>>> Matrix(1, 5)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
Vector(nrows=1, ncols=5)
```

Mind that instances are actually created inside the `__new__()` method, while `__init__()` is used for initializing the newly created instance.

Also, as mentioned in a comment below by [@Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght), creating a `Vector` instance through the Matrix class can lead to unwanted surprises, such as as the `Vector`'s `__init__()` method not getting called (it would have to be called manually).

Depending on your use case, though, it might thus be better to keep things clean and just use a *factory* for instance creation:

```
class Matrix: 
    def __init__(self, nrows, ncols):
        self.nrows = nrows
        self.ncols = ncols

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}(nrows={}, ncols={})'.format(
            self.__class__.__name__, self.nrows, self.ncols)

class Vector(Matrix):
    pass

def make_matrix(nrows, ncols):
    if nrows == 1:
        return Vector(nrows, ncols)
    return Matrix(nrows, ncols)
```

Demo:

```
>>> make_matrix(1, 5)
Vector(nrows=1, ncols=5)
>>> make_matrix(2, 5)
Matrix(nrows=2, ncols=5)
```

Of course `make_matrix()` could also be implemented as a (class/static) method of the `Matrix` class, but that would make the parent class more tightly coupled with one of its child classes...

Comment: One warning about using `__new__` in this situation: A class's `__init__` method only gets called if its instance is created by a call to its own class. When you create an instance of `Vector` by calling `Vector.__new__` from `Matrix.__new__`, no `__init__` method will be called on it. Trying to call `Vector` directly on the other hand will lead to infinite recursion (since `Vector` inherits `Matrix.__new__` unless you override it).

Comment: This is a valid remark and another reason for not recommending doing that, I would rather go with a factory. Thanks for mentioning this.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I had never seen this `__new__` method. I'll try both methods a see which is best suited. I think your factory solution is the most pythonic and natural solution.